# React-Native, Facebook Login stops the app, console log shows no errors

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, facebook-login

I'm going insane here. I've followed the steps on this guide to integrate Facebook Sign in to my app: https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/integrating-fbsdk-facebook-login-in-react-native-7b7600ce74a7.

But whenever I attempt to sign in the app just stops on my emulator, no error message, even with try catch, the app just stops.

Here's how my Android manifest currently looks:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's my strings xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Nearalize</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">630642072562453</string>
</resources>
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    SafeAreaView, 
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Text, 
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';


const handleFacebookSignIn = ({ isRegister, navigation }) => {
  console.log('Facebook login was attempted 4');
  LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
    result => {
      console.log('Facebook login was executed');
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('Facebook login was canceled');
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Facebook login was successful with permissions: ',
          result.grantedPermissions
        );
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Facebook login failed with error: ', error);
      // Handle login failure, e.g., show an error message.
    }
  );
};

const SignInButton = ({ backgroundColor, textColor, imageSource, imageTintColor, circleColor, text, onPress  }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress} // Use the onPress prop here
      style={[sign_in_button_styles.button, {backgroundColor}]}
    >
      <View style={[sign_in_button_styles.innerView, {backgroundColor: circleColor}]}>
        <Image
          style={[sign_in_button_styles.image, {tintColor: imageTintColor}]}
          source={imageSource}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={[sign_in_button_styles.text, {color: textColor}]}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const RenderInteralComponent = (navigation, isRegister) => {
    const {colors} = useTheme();
    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            style={{
                flex:1,
                backgroundColor:colors.cardBg,
            }}
        >
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>
                <LogoPresentation/>
                <View>
                <Text style={[FONTS.h2,{textAlign:'center',color:colors.title,marginBottom:5}]}>{isRegister ? 'Sign In Quickly' : 'Log In Quickly'}</Text>
                <Text style={[FONTS.font,{fontSize:16,textAlign:'center',color:colors.title,opacity:.7}]}>{isRegister ? 'You can sign with the following' : 'You can log in with the following'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View
                style={{
                        paddingHorizontal:35,
                        paddingVertical:20,
                    }}
                >
                    <SignInButton
                    backgroundColor='#305CCD'
                    textColor={COLORS.white}
                    imageSource={IMAGES.fb}
                    imageTintColor={COLORS.white}
                    text= "Facebook"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isRegister={isRegister}
                    isPhoneAuth={false}
                    circleColor= 'rgba(255,255,255,.15)'
                    onPress={handleFacebookSignIn}
                    />
                </View> 
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const Authentication = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const {isRegister} = route.params;
    return (
        <OnBoardingContainer
        navigation = {navigation}
        childComponentInternal={() => RenderInteralComponent(navigation, isRegister)}
        errorMessage={""}
      />    
    );
};
```

Here's all the relevant screenshots from my facebook developer portal configuration, notice that when I log in to my facebook account, the app does appear on the linked app list: [[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTNbC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg27a.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDFAN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS6vR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx6NX.png)

I tried to log in to my app using the facebook sdk (my app has not been reviewed but I used an admin account). I was expecting the log in attempt to be succesful without the app stopping.